# Blinking dashes on top of unity

Tags: 12.10, display

[image]

There are a bunch of dashes like this at the top of the screen. I'm not sure how to even begin identifying what is causing this. Here are some of the things that I've noticed.

- I can't use ctrl+alt+f1 the top half of the screen just flashes and nothing happens.

Tell me what you need to diagnose this issue.

ATI Radeon HD 5670, most recent catalyst driver installed.

Comment: Are you using proprietry drivers?

Comment: Proprietary drivers for what?

Comment: Sorry meant to say video card there.

Comment: It was a dumb question on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed the steps here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

```
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.BAK
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

Rebooted, lines gone.